# how to get a mask of an image so that i can use it in the inpainting function

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

i want my mask to be black obviously and the red line which is my region of interest to be white so that i can use it inside the inpainting function...! am having this code but it not working

How to concentrate on a particular part of the image... because my mask image is showing all the image... this is the image[image] and code
[image]

```
    cv::inRange(img, cv::Scalar(0, 100, 220), cv::Scalar(10, 255, 255), lower);

    cv::inRange(img, cv::Scalar(0, 10, 100), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), upper);

   threshold(mask, mask,10,255, CV_THRESH_BINARY); 

   inpaint(img, mask, inpainted,3,CV_INPAINT_TELEA);
```

Comment: A mask is supposed to be black and white. This mask can be used on a color image, where it determines what is and what is not shown, using black and white.  Can you add an image of the mask?

Comment: yea, the mast is supposed to be black and the area i want should be with but mine is not the case, every part of the picture is showing an the area i want to concentrate on is black, making the output image not correct...

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your input image, the output you're getting, and  the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   Mat img = imread("Lennared.jpg"); 

    Mat mask, inpainted;

    cvtcolor(img,mask,CV_BRG2GRAY);

    inrange(img, Scalar(10,10,200), Scalar(40,40,255),mask); // make sure your 
    targeted color is between the range you stated

    inpaint(img,mask, inpainted,3,CV_INPAINT_TELEA);

    for( int key =0 ; 23 !-key; key=waitKey())

    {
        switch (key)
    {
       case 'm' : imshow("maskimage", mask)

    break;

    case 'i': imshow("inpainted image", inpainted)

    break;

    default : imshow("original" img);


    }


    }

    return 0;
```

since am i trying to detect the red color in the image, i have to pass the scalar value of the red color, that from a lower range to a higher range all inclusive...  That should give you the perfect mask image for use in the inpaint function, hope this help everyone else ..